# Pyspark does not release memory even after its operation completed

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

As per my currently requirement, I am using Pyspark with flask apis(Python Framework) and I am creating Spark session while flask apis server getting up. And I am using spark session for heavy wait computing while api call. So here what happen in each api request, Memory size increased even after its operation are done.

I have did following after each apis called

```
1: spark.catalog.clearCache()
2: df.unpersist()
```

Even my memory is gradually increased.

Any one help me to come out from this big issue. I have tring different different configuration even my memory is not reduced.

Answer (score 4):

[`unpersist()`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/3.0.1/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.DataFrame.unpersist) is by default `unpersist(blocking=false)`, which means it's just a flag on your dataframe, saying that Spark can delete it whenever possible. Meanwhile, `unpersist(blocking=true)` will **block** your process instead

Comment: It is still increased memory but at reaching near to max size. it become constant. is there any option to reduce immediate after its operation completed.

Comment: That sounds right: the memory will get increased, and when Garbage Collector is kicked in, your cached dataframe with unpersist flag will be purged. You don't control Garbage Collector manually. Also, if you're **willing to wait** until it's purged, use `blocking=True`

Comment: Is there any way to stop or closed Pyspark session(Java process)? here I observed that even after operation completed, Java process occupied memory and that not be  released event after completed operation and even after sometimes.