# Why unpersist() does not remove my path from the cache in pyspark in Azure Databricks?

Tags: caching, pyspark, databricks, azure-databricks

I am reading a bench of csv file at a specific path :

```
spark.read.format('csv').load('/mnt/path/')
```

I am caching my dataframe in order to access corrupt records [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67233611/how-can-i-query-corrupt-records-without-caching-the-data-with-pyspark-in-azure-d)

```
data_frame.cache()
```

At the end of my notebook, i want to remove this path from the cache by using `data_frame.unpersist()`

Then I am changing the underlying data, for example deleting or adding new files to the table path

But if i read again the csv, `spark.read.format('csv').load('/mnt/path/')`, spark does not have the last changes, **it still shows the cached data**.

Which makes me think that the dataframe is not really uncached.

The only way it can work out, it is restarting the cluster.

I dont want to use `spark.catalog.clearCache()` as this would impact caching all the jobs running on the cluster. I only want to uncache the specific dataframe from the current notebook.

Any suggestion or observation would be much appreciated.

---

edit :
I was not assigning it to my dataframe. It looks like there is a difference between
`data_frame = data_frame.unpersist()` and `data_frame.unpersist()`

Comment: Show the code in its entirety i suggest

Comment: Maybe you can find your answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/69272166/3441510?

Answer (score 1):

Try adding blocking flag set to true so that your computation waits until that cached data is really removed.

```
[ def unpersist(blocking: Boolean) ]
data_frame.unpersist(true)
```